# How to store the contents of a list non persistently in java

Tags: java, persistence

In my application i have a set of file which contains some information.Now what i have to do i have to process the files and among those files which are duplicate i have to skip them so to do that i have used file CRC to check which files are processed and which are not,so now in the case of duplicate checking i have to store the file CRC to some where because when today's processing is over then i will have to process the file again tomorrow.Then if some file are duplicate of today those should be skipped. so now what i have done in my code is..

```
               filesSize += fileInf.srcFileSize;
                // if file if already polled and under processing or in execution queue
                if (filesInQueue.get(fileInf.srcFileCRC) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Skipping queued file: " + fileInf.srcFileName);
                    ifCRCExist.add(fileInf.srcFileCRC);
```

fileInf.srcFileCRC, is the required fileCRC which i have added to the list now i have store the list non persistently some where which i can use to check the record later..I think i am clear now..Please any one help me..

Comment: Are you talking about storing the content of your list to your HDD?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking for. If you can edit your question to include some of your code and demonstrate more clearly what your trying to achieve it will be easier for people to help you.

Comment: @Rudi i have done editing can you help now??

Answer (score 1):

Each instance in Java is transient by nature. Are you in search of a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)? You may provide the `ArrayList` as a static field of some `Class`. For example:

```
public class InMemoryStore {
    public static final List<String> MY_SINGLETON_LIST;

    static {
        MY_SINGLETON_LIST = ...
    }
}
```

Or you may do it by creating a bean with Spring, for example.

Comment: Then how will i save the contents of the list

Comment: Didn't you asked for a non persistent list? If you like to save it (for example to a file) it is persistent.

Comment: i am new to it can you give me reference of that

Comment: actually i am trying to use something in memory that will not physically store it

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non persistent storage means not in DB or XML then make a class
and create a **static** list member. Now you can use it as many times by initializing only once. Just like **Singleton** pattern.